# Directed Acyclic Graph and its Topological Sorting (assign priorities)

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph, scheduling, directed-acyclic-graphs

I have a directed acyclic graph like the one shown in the image below.

The thing I want to achieve is to obtain a **topological ordering where every node has a priority `p` later used for scheduling (where a higher value means a higher priority)

A topological sorting like the linear list in the visualization below can be computed in linear time by visiting each node and edge once (O(|V| + |E|) (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting#Depth-first_search)

However, when the task of assigning priorities comes into play, I cannot find a better algorithm so far than doing the thing below.

1. Assign to every node `n` in graph `g` the priority `p=0`.
2. for every node `n` in graph `g`:

   - start a depth-first recursion from node `n`

     - while traversing down the subgraph from `n`

       - if a parent node **already has a higher priority** as the current node, **you don't need to go deeper**, and you can continue with other nodes in the depth-first recursion.
       - if the priority is equal or lower, 
         set the priority of the parent nodes to the priority of 
         the current node + 1 and **visit the parent**.

*(there are some small optimizations: ignoring subgraphs from which we already started a DFS and only increasing the subgraphs priority offset, each nodes priority is then calculated by its local priority + its subgraphs priority offset)*

Each depth-first recursion starting from `n` cannot be made simpler by ignoring already visited nodes inside the for loop above, like it can be done for a simple topological sort (linear list in image, (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting#Depth-first_search))

Is it better to first compute the topological ordering (O(|V| + |E|) and then iterate over the linear list and assign priorities (O(|V| + |E|)?
I would like to have a less distinct priorities as possible to allow for paralle scheduling (node D and E can be scheduled at the same time in the image)

[image: Topological Sort by Assigning Priorities]

Comment: Can you define the priority function other than by an algorithm that computes it? It isn't very clear what it should be.

Comment: its basically  iff node n1 and n2 and  n1 < n2  then  priority(n1) > priority(n2)

Comment: this question is probably answered by this question: 
http://stackoverflow.com/a/3421005/293195
but I don't quite understand how it works in detail

Comment: Is this the only requirement? There are many functions that satisfy it, the simplest being priority(n) = the index of n in the output of toposort.

Comment: thats true, that is already a feasible priority assignment, but I try to optimize for as less disitinct priorities as possible (for parallel scheduling, so in the image above both D and E can be scheduled at the same time)

Comment: That answer is absolutely correct and I don't see what kind of problem is there. Basically you run the toposort then walk the result from min to max and assign priority i to the i-th node.

Comment: The thing is my algorithm description does not exactly do this, and I am wondering if it is as fast or worse than first topo sort and then walking through the result. Or in other words, can we already assign priorities when ideally doing a topo sorting (visiting each edge and node once) -> I dont think that is possible

Comment: As less distinct priorities as possible --- you still walk the nodes from min to max, but this time you assign `priority(node) = 1+max_{k=1..node.children}(priority(node.child[k]))`. Assign zero for nodes with no children. This us still O(V+E).

Comment: "can we already assign priorities when ideally doing a topo sorting" --- could you be looking for the [Coffman–Graham algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coffman%E2%80%93Graham_algorithm)?

Comment: i dont know, because I dont understand the Coffman-Graham algorithm so far, or better said, what its other requirements are..., it is a an algorithm for scheduling with some restrictions of having a fixed amount or processors?

Comment: Yes it is, is this what you want?