# Computing level of nodes in a graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, depth-first-search

I want to compute the level of each node in a directed graph. I'm currently applying a depth-first search algorithm on vertices that have no incoming edges. Considering the graph below, for instance:

[image]

The expected result is:

```
Vertex | Level
1      | 0
2      | 1
3      | 2
4      | 1
5      | 3
6      | 4
```

In this particular case, if we start by applying DFS on 4, then all results for vertices 4, 3, 5 and 6 are going to be wrong, since 1 has level 0. I've tried to always consider the greatest result for each one of the nodes, so in this case the results for 3, 5, and 6 are replaced when applying DFS on 1. It works, but I can't find a way to correctly compute the level of vertex 4.

I'm working only with directed acyclic graphs.

I'm not including any code here because it is a pretty straightforward DFS implementation and I'm not struggling implementation-wise.

Any hint would be much appreciated.

Comment: I think it only does make sense to talk about the levels of each node in a tree. What you have there is certainly not a tree. The characteristics of a tree would include the fact that each node has at most one edge which points towards them.

Comment: is your graph directed acyclic ?

Comment: @ErvinSzilagyi Aren't you mixing up level and depth? I think what you're saying is true but for depth.

Comment: @nits.kk Yes, I'm gonna include this information on my question.

Comment: Why wouldn't the level of Vertex 5 be 3, i.e. one more that Vertex 3? Similarly for Vertex 6 - why isn't it at level 4?

Comment: @SirRaffleBuffle Sorry about that. It was a typo.

Comment: Take a look at this previous question - [How to assign “levels” to vertices of an acyclic directed graph?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3420685/how-to-assign-levels-to-vertices-of-an-acyclic-directed-graph). I think the solution there would work for you, but you'd need to "invert" the levels.

Answer (score 1):

You can compute the levels starting from each vertex without having an incoming edge. Then you can store the maximum value for each vertex until the end. For eg :- Vertex 3 will have values 1 and 2 when traversed from starting points vertex 1 and vertex 4 respectively. At last, you can update the vertices not having the incoming edge(number on child -1). If there's a situation where there multiple children of such a vertex, then you might want to select the child with maximum number on it for replacement and then run the algorithm from that vertex again to see if changes the numbers assigned to any of the other children.